# Get the selected Items in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm building a View where the user can select some companies and after selecting some companies I can click on a buttong and do something.
The problem is that I couldn't bind the selected companies in the ViewModel.

Here are what I have:

**The ViewModel:**

```
public class ParametrosPesquisaViewModel
{
    public ParametrosPesquisaViewModel()
    {            
        Empresas = new List<EmpresaViewModel>();         
    }

    public IList<EmpresaViewModel> Empresas { get; set; }       
}
```

**The Controller:**

**Get**

```
   public ActionResult Pesquisa()
    {
        ParametrosPesquisaViewModel parametros = new ParametrosPesquisaViewModel();
        var empresas = _empresaAppService.BuscarEmpresasValidas();            

        foreach (EmpresaViewModel empresa in empresas)
        {
            //Simulando a empresa logada                
            empresa.Selecionada = empresa.empresa == 1;                                
            parametros.Empresas.Add(empresa);
        }

        return View(parametros);
    }
```

**Post**

```
public ActionResult Pesquisa(ParametrosPesquisaViewModel parametros)
{
    //Do something
}
```

**Html:**

```
@model LMX.RecuperadorCupomFiscal.Application.ViewModels.ParametrosPesquisaViewModel

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Pesquisa", "RecuperadorCupomFiscal", FormMethod.Post))
        {
    ... skipping some html code
                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    <label for="Empresa">Empresa(s):</label>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <label for="cidade_emp">Cidade</label>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <label for="estado_emp">Estado</label>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var empresa in Model.Empresas)
                            {                            
                                <tr>
                                    <td>                                    
                                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => empresa.Selecionada)                                            
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => empresa.NomeEmpresaCodigo)                                    

                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => empresa.cidade_emp)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => empresa.estado_emp)
                                    </td>
                                </tr>                            
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>


        }
```

In the Post ActionResult, the parametros.Empresas is not getting the binding.
What is the best approach for this case?

Comment: You can use Editor Template to handle this. Take a look at [How to know the selected checkboxes from within the HttpPost Create action method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961222/how-to-know-the-selected-checkboxes-from-within-the-httppost-create-action-metho)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are generating checkboxes, model binder won't be able to bind submitted data. Instead, try rewriting your loop this way:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Empresas.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.Empresas[i].Selecionada)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Empresas[i].NomeEmpresaCodigo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Empresas[i].cidade_emp)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Empresas[i].estado_emp)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: It is about time microsoft "fixed" this. Everyone makes this mistake at some point which makes you think the implementation must be incorrect

Comment: @sachin, you got the point. Thank you