# CheckBoxList using ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having trouble understanding how to retrieve data from my Device table in my database to a CheckBoxList.

I believe I have the Models, ViewModel and Database setup properly but I'm just not sure what to do next. For now, I would simple like to learn how to retrieve the data from my table to a CheckBoxList.

**Customer Model**

```
    public class Customer
{
    public int CustId { get; set; }
    public string CustDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string CustFirstName { get; set; }
    public string CustLastName { get; set; }
    public string CustCompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CustAddress { get; set; }
    public string CustPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string CustMobileNumber { get; set; }
    public string CustEmailAddress { get; set; }

    public int StId { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
}
```

**State Model**

```
    public class State
{
    public int StId { get; set; }
    public string StAbbr { get; set; }

    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

**Device Model**

```
    public class Device
{
    public int DevId { get; set; }
    public string DevType { get; set; }
    public bool isChecked { get; set; }
}
```

**CustomerDevice Model**

```
    public class CustomerDevice
{
    public int CustId { get; set; }
    public int DevId { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public Device Device { get; set; }
}
```

**CustomerViewModel**

```
public class CustomerFormViewModel
{
    public int CustId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Display Name")]
    [Display(Name = "Display Name")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string CustDisplayName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CustFirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CustLastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CustCompanyName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [StringLength(12)]
    public string CustPhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Mobile Number")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [StringLength(12)]
    public string CustMobileNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [StringLength(320)]
    public string CustEmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Address")]
    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string CustAddress { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select State")]
    [Display(Name = "State")]
    public int StId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<State> States { get; set; }
}
```

**CustomerController**

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    private CoreWebAppContext _context;

    public CustomerController(CoreWebAppContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }


    // GET: /<controller>/
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_context.Customers.ToList());
    }


    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var states = _context.States.ToList();
        var viewModel = new CustomerFormViewModel
        {
            States = states
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(CustomerFormViewModel vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var customer = new Customer();
            {
                customer.CustDisplayName = vm.CustDisplayName;
                customer.CustFirstName = vm.CustFirstName;
                customer.CustLastName = vm.CustLastName;
                customer.CustCompanyName = vm.CustCompanyName;
                customer.CustAddress = vm.CustAddress;
                customer.CustPhoneNumber = vm.CustPhoneNumber;
                customer.CustMobileNumber = vm.CustMobileNumber;
                customer.CustEmailAddress = vm.CustEmailAddress;
                customer.StId = vm.StId;
            }
            _context.Customers.Add(customer);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        else
        {
            vm.States = _context.States.ToList();
            return View(vm);
        }
    }


    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var customervm = new CustomerFormViewModel();
        {
            Customer customer = _context.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustId == id);

            if (customer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            customervm.CustId = customer.CustId;
            customervm.CustDisplayName = customer.CustDisplayName;
            customervm.CustFirstName = customer.CustFirstName;
            customervm.CustLastName = customer.CustLastName;
            customervm.CustCompanyName = customer.CustCompanyName;
            customervm.CustAddress = customer.CustAddress;
            customervm.CustPhoneNumber = customer.CustPhoneNumber;
            customervm.CustMobileNumber = customer.CustMobileNumber;
            customervm.CustEmailAddress = customer.CustEmailAddress;

            // Retrieve list of States
            var states = _context.States.ToList();
            customervm.States = states;

            // Set the selected state
            customervm.StId = customer.StId;
        }
        return View(customervm);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(CustomerFormViewModel vmEdit)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Customer customer = _context.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustId == vmEdit.CustId);

            if (customer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            customer.CustDisplayName = vmEdit.CustDisplayName;
            customer.CustFirstName = vmEdit.CustFirstName;
            customer.CustLastName = vmEdit.CustLastName;
            customer.CustCompanyName = vmEdit.CustCompanyName;
            customer.CustAddress = vmEdit.CustAddress;
            customer.CustPhoneNumber = vmEdit.CustPhoneNumber;
            customer.CustMobileNumber = vmEdit.CustMobileNumber;
            customer.CustEmailAddress = vmEdit.CustEmailAddress;
            customer.StId = vmEdit.StId;

            _context.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(vmEdit);
    }


}
```

**Create View**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustDisplayName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustDisplayName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.CustDisplayName)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustFirstName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustFirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustLastName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustLastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustCompanyName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustCompanyName, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustAddress)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustAddress, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.CustAddress)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustPhoneNumber)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustPhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.CustPhoneNumber)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustMobileNumber)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustMobileNumber, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.CustMobileNumber)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustEmailAddress)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustEmailAddress, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.CustEmailAddress)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(s => s.StId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(s => s.StId, new SelectList(Model.States, "StId", "StAbbr"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(s => s.StId)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at the [Editor template sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961222/how-to-know-the-selected-checkboxes-from-within-the-httppost-create-action-metho/38964032#38964032)

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve my Device data to a CheckBoxList without using the Editor Template? Sorry, just a little confused on how to retrieve the Device data to the Create View. In the future after I learn how to at least populate the CheckBoxList I will need to learn how to assign selected checkbox values to a Customer based on the Customer's ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make another ViewModel class called `IndexViewModel` and put this on it:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public List<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

Here is your controller Action. Return the new IndexViewModel instead:

```
// GET: /<controller>/
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View(_context.Customers.ToList());
}
```

to

```
// GET: /<controller>/
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new IndexViewModel();
    model.Customers = _context.Customers.ToList();
    model.Devices = _context.Devices.ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

In your view, simply iterate the Device list:

```
@{
    for(int i = 0; i < Model.Devices.Count(); i++)
    {
        var checkboxAttributes = Model.Devices[i].isChecked == true ?
            (object) new { @class = "checkbox", @checked = "checked" } :
            (object) new { @class = "checkbox" };

        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Devices[i].DevType, checkboxAttributes)
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Devices[i].DevType, new { @class = "label" })
    }
}
```

**Update 1**

I'm sorry about the previous one but this is the correct version: It uses bootstrap style for the checkbox:

```
@{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Devices.Count(); i++)
    {
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Devices[i].DevId)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Devices[i].isChecked)
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Devices[i].DevType)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Devices[i].DevType)
            </label>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: @Christian, I have a red line on the following line of code `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Devices[i].DevType, checkboxAttributes)`. The error message says ** Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' or 'bool' Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type.**

Comment: Yes it's a mistake there, take a look at the revised code.

Comment: my **Device** Model above has the same 3 columns in my **Device** Table in my Database. Do I need the column **isChecked** in my Device Table? If I remove the column **isChecked** from my Device Table I get the following error message below on this line `var devices = _context.Devices.ToList();`  The error message says **An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Invalid column name 'isChecked'.**

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this, so you can reuse it for different models.

**CheckboxViewModel:**

```
public class CheckboxViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

**Extension method:**

```
public static IEnumerable<CheckboxViewModel> CreateCheckboxList<T>(this List<T> entities, Func<T, object> value, Func<T, object> text, Func<T, bool> isChecked)
    {
        return entities.Select(x => new CheckboxViewModel
        {
            Id = (int)value(x),
            Name = text(x).ToString(),
            Checked = isChecked(x)
        });
    }
```

**Using example:**

```
result = devices.CreateCheckboxList(x => x.Id, x => x.Name, x => selectedDevices.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();

@for (var deviceIndex = 0; deviceIndex < Model.Devices.Count(); deviceIndex ++)
                            {
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Devices[deviceIndex ].Id)
                                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Devices[deviceIndex ].Checked)
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Devices[deviceIndex ].Checked, Model.Devices[deviceIndex ].Name)
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            }
```

Comment: Nice answer. Only problem I had was the cast for Id in the extension. Use int.Parse instead.