# ASP.NET Core MVC Edit CheckBoxList values in Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having trouble understanding how to update the CheckBoxList values to the CustomerDevice table in my Database on the [HttpPost] Edit Action Method CustomerDeviceController.

My Index Action Method for the CustomerDeviceController displays a list of Customers from my Customers table. I have an ActionLink labeled "Edit" that passes the CustId value to the CustomerDeviceController [HttpGet] Edit(int? id) Action Method which then displays all selected DevId values assigned to the CustId to the CheckBoxList, this part works fine.

When I try to update the CheckBoxList values now I get the following error message below. I was told that I would need to loop through and delete the DevId values before I could update them. This is the part I'm having trouble understanding.

**Error Message when updating CheckBoxList**

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The instance of entity type 'CustomerDevice' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked. When adding new entities, for most key types a unique temporary key value will be created if no key is set (i.e. if the key property is assigned the default value for its type). If you are explicitly setting key values for new entities, ensure they do not collide with existing entities or temporary values generated for other new entities. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached to the context.

**Models**

```
    public class CheckBoxListItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Display { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}

    public class Customer
{
    public int CustId { get; set; }
    public string CustDisplayName { get; set; }
    ...
}

    public class Device
{
    public int DevId { get; set; }
    public string DevType { get; set; }
}

    public class CustomerDevice
{
    public int CustId { get; set; }
    public int DevId { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public Device Device { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModels**

```
    public class CustomerDeviceFormViewModel
{
    public int CustId { get; set; }
    public string CustDisplayName { get; set; }
    public List<CheckBoxListItem> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

**CustomerDeviceController**

```
public ActionResult Create(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var customervm = new CustomerDeviceFormViewModel();
        {
            Customer customer = db.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustId == id);

            if (customer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            customervm.CustId = customer.CustId;
            customervm.CustDisplayName = customer.CustDisplayName;

            // Retrieves list of Devices for CheckBoxList
            var deviceList = db.Devices.ToList();
            var checkBoxListItems = new List<CheckBoxListItem>();
            foreach (var device in deviceList)
            {
                checkBoxListItems.Add(new CheckBoxListItem()
                {
                    ID = device.DevId,
                    Display = device.DevType,
                    IsChecked = false //On the create view, no devices are selected by default
                });
            }

            customervm.Devices = checkBoxListItems;
            return View(customervm);
        }
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(CustomerDeviceFormViewModel vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var deviceId in vm.Devices.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.ID))
            {
                var customerDevices = new CustomerDevice
                {
                    CustId = vm.CustId,
                    DevId = deviceId
                };

                db.CustomerDevices.Add(customerDevices);
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(vm);
    }


    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        Customer customer = db.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustId == id);
        if (customer == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        // Get all devices
        var deviceList = db.Devices.ToList();
        // Get the selected device ID's for the customer
        IEnumerable<int> selectedDevices = db.CustomerDevices
            .Where(x => x.CustId == id).Select(x => x.DevId);
        // Build view model
        var model = new CustomerDeviceFormViewModel()
        {
            CustId = customer.CustId,
            CustDisplayName = customer.CustDisplayName,
            Devices = deviceList.Select(x => new CheckBoxListItem()
            {
                ID = x.DevId,
                Display = x.DevType,
                IsChecked = selectedDevices.Contains(x.DevId)
            }).ToList()
        };
        return View(model);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(CustomerDeviceFormViewModel vmEdit)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Customer customer = db.Customers
                       .Include(c => c.CustomerDevices)
                       .SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustId == vmEdit.CustId);

            if (customer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            IEnumerable<int> selectedDevices = vmEdit.Devices.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.ID);

            // Remove all selected devices for this customer
            foreach (int removeId in selectedDevices)
            {
                customer.CustomerDevices.Clear();
            }


            // Add the new selected devices
            foreach (int deviceId in selectedDevices)
            {
                CustomerDevice customerDevice = new CustomerDevice
                {
                    CustId = customer.CustId,
                    DevId = deviceId
                };
                customer.CustomerDevices.Add(customerDevice);        
            }

            // Update the customer
            db.Customers.Update(customer); //or just db.Update(customer); same thing
            //                               // Save and redirect
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(vmEdit);
    }
```

**Edit View**

```
    <div class="form-group">
    Please select the Devices to assign to <b>@Html.DisplayFor(c => c.CustDisplayName)</b>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Devices)
</div>

@Html.HiddenFor(c => c.CustId)

<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
```

**Shared/EditorTemplates/CheckBoxListItem.chtml**

```
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsChecked)
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.IsChecked, Model.Display)
</label>
<br />
```

**WebFormContext**

```
public class WebFormContext : DbContext
{
    public WebFormContext(DbContextOptions<WebFormContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<State> States { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CustomerDevice> CustomerDevices { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .HasKey(c => c.CustId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .Property(c => c.CustDisplayName)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(100)")
            .HasMaxLength(100)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .Property(c => c.CustFirstName)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .Property(c => c.CustLastName)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .Property(c => c.CustCompanyName)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .Property(c => c.CustAddress)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(100)")
            .HasMaxLength(100)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .Property(c => c.CustPhoneNumber)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(12)")
            .HasMaxLength(12);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .Property(c => c.CustMobileNumber)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(12)")
            .HasMaxLength(12);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .Property(c => c.CustEmailAddress)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(320)")
            .HasMaxLength(320);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Device>()
            .HasKey(d => d.DevId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Device>()
            .Property(d => d.DevType)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerDevice>()
            .HasKey(cd => new { cd.CustId, cd.DevId });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are trying to do a many to many edit from what I understand.

First you should have a look at this [Many-To-Many](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#many-to-many). You will need to update your models like in the example and also add the relationship manually in the OnModelCreating method. Also don't forget to add the DbSet for it on your DB context.

In Customer and Device model add:

`public List<CustomerDevice> CustomerDevices{ get; set; }`

In WebFormContext OnModelCreating you should have:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerDevice>()
            .HasKey(c => new { c.CustId, c.DevId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerDevice>()
            .HasOne(cd => cd.Customer)
            .WithMany(c => c.CustomerDevices)
            .HasForeignKey(cd => cd.CustId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerDevice>()
            .HasOne(cd => cd.Device)
            .WithMany(d => d.CustomerDevices)
            .HasForeignKey(cd => cd.DevId);
```

After that you can use include to eagerly load the related objects (in the **Edit** action for example) [(see more about that)](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/related-data.html):

```
Customer customer = db.Customers
                   .Include(c => c.CustomerDevices)
                   .SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustId == id);
```

Then you should only do operations on the detached customer.

```
customer.CustomerDevices.Add(...);
customer.CustomerDevices.Remove(...);
//edit
```

After that save the changes to your customer

```
db.Customers.Update(customer);
db.SaveChanges();
```

In your case you can do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(CustomerDeviceFormViewModel vmEdit)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Customer customer = db.Customers
                   .Include(c => c.CustomerDevices)
                   .SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustId == id);

        if (customer == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        IEnumerable<int> selectedDevices = vmEdit.Devices.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.ID);

        // Add the new selected devices
        foreach (int deviceId in selectedDevices)
        {
           var customerDevice = customer.CustomerDevices.FirstOrDefault(cd => cd.DevId == deviceId);
            if(customerDevice != null)
            {
                 customer.CustomerDevices.Remove(customerDevice);
            }
            else
            {
                CustomerDevice customerDevice = new CustomerDevice
                {
                    CustId = customer.Id,
                    DevId = deviceId
                };
                customer.CustomerDevices.Add(customerDevice);
            }
        }

        // Update the customer
        db.Customers.Update(customer); //or just db.Update(customer); same thing
        // Save and redirect
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(vmEdit);
}
```

Comment: I edited my post to include my **OnModelCreating Method**. I'm not sure how or were to eagerly load the related objects in my OnModelCreating Method. Also, is the `Customer customer = db.Customers
                   .Include(c => c.CustomerDevices)
                   .SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustId == id);` for the EditPost Method? Can you also help me with the `customer.CustomerDevices.Add(...);
` and `customer.CustomerDevices.Remove(...);`//edit

Comment: Please see my updated post. You still have to change your models by adding a list of CustomerDevices in both Customer and Device and you missed the many to many relationship in the OnModelCreating. I also added an example on how you could implement the edit action.

Comment: As a side note you have chosen your model ID's very bad. By convention, a property named Id or <type name>Id will be configured as the key of an entity. Otherwise you have to set that up yourself. See https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/keys.html

Comment: Ok, I made the following changes that you recommended but I'm still getting the same error above **Error Message when updating CheckBoxList** when updating. If I completely remove the selected values to that user and add new values it's fine. But if I select new values and keep one of the older values then I get that error.

Comment: I also had to modify `Customer customer = db.Customers
                   .Include(c => c.CustomerDevices)
                   .SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustId == id);` to `Customer customer = db.Customers
                   .Include(c => c.CustomerDevices)
                   .SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustId == vmEdit.CustId);`

Comment: @korn31 Do I need to somehow have two separate transactions for `customer.CustomerDevices.Clear();` and `db.Customers.Update(customer);`?

Comment: I feel that I don't have the whole info. In my example there is no CheckBoxList so I don't understand why you get that error. Furthermore I see that you have a CheckBoxListItem model. Do you use that ? Why ? I don't see the purpose of it since you know what devices are selected from the CustomerDevices list. In my example there is only one transaction. `customer.CustomerDevices.Clear();` isn't a transaction

Comment: @korn31 I use the CheckBoxListItem model along with the Shared/EditorTemplate/CheckBoxListItem.chtml for retrieving and binding the CheckBoxList values from the Devices table to the CheckBoxList. That was a recommendation that I got from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961222/how-to-know-the-selected-checkboxes-from-within-the-httppost-create-action-metho/38964032#38964032

Comment: @korn31, I updated the **CustomerDeviceController** in my original post to show how I'm using the **CheckBoxList** Model along with the **CheckBoxListItem.chtml** EditorTemplate.

Comment: Usually when you have a situation like yours you use a multiselect dropdown. There are solutions out there like [bootstrap-multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) that even have checkboxes.

Comment: I would prefer to stay away from third party plugins and just do this all with ASP.NET Core MVC. It's crazy, I look at what you supplied and it logically makes sense to me. Just can't figure out why I can't include an already selected value within the update. I can only add new DevId values and cannot include a preselected value when I update.

Comment: I updated the post. There was a problem when clearing the list and adding the same ones. We should only remove the ones that were removed.

Comment: I cleated a repository [here](https://github.com/korn3l/AspNetCore-Many-to-Many) that works fine for me, but it uses select lists. Have a look there.

Comment: I had to rename `.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustId == id);` **to** `.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustId == vmEdit.CustId);`. I had to rename `CustomerDevice customerDevice = new CustomerDevice` **to** `CustomerDevice custDevice = new CustomerDevice` since `customerDevice` was using as a local scope. Then rename `CustId = customer.Id,` **to** `CustId = customer.CustId`.

Comment: Ok, almost there. Now, just a little problem still. Example: If I initially added DevId values (1, 3, 4 and 7) for CustId 1006 and then decide to Edit to remove just DevId value 1 it actually removes DevId values (3, 4 and 7) and leaves DevId value 1.

Comment: So it seems to add the DevId values that I choose to remove and the DevId values that I want to keep it removes.

Comment: Still having trouble figuring out why the DevId values that I want to remove it adds and the DevId values that I want to keep it removes. It's backwards :)